# Programmatically View Windows Security Options

Tags: windows, security, winapi, pywin32

I'm trying to view (and possible edit, but that's not super important) the Windows Security Options as shown below:
[Local Security Policy > Security Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O2rG.png)

I've been able to edit password policies with: *NetUserModalsGet* and Audit Policies with *GetPolicyHandle*, but can't seem to find the Security Options.

I'm currently trying to stick to *[pywin32](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/)*, but at this point I'm open to *any* method of getting this information without having to open the GUI.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45905569/programmatical-manipulation-of-windows-local-security-policy ?

Comment: Not really a duplication. 45905569 gets an answer from 'vrdse', which only describes User Rights Assignment and Audit Policy Settings (which I was able to find the api for), but NOT about the Security Options. 'vrdse' says that the question should be more specific about a setting. Then how would you view: ***Interactive logon: Do not require CTRL+ALT+DEL***.  Additionally, the author says that the settings can be modified by setting registry values. However, those registry items don't seem to be set by default, therefore they can't be viewed.